# android:load image from sdcard with picasso

Tags: android, image, imageview, picasso

is it possible to use [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library to load image from sdcard to imageView ?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Do some search on internet you will get many examples.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) doc provided,

> Resources, assets, files, content providers are all supported as
>   image sources.

You can simply do like it

```
String filename = "YOURIMAGE.png";
String path = "/mnt/sdcard/" + filename;
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(path)).into(imageView);
```

**Edit**

As @Budius suggested, the better way to access file from disk path, use `Enviroment` class.

```
String filename = "YOURIMAGE.png";
String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(baseDir + File.separator + filename)).into(imageView);
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: I know the answer is correct on how to call picasso with file, but please, do never hard code a disk path like that. Alternatively use one of the many `get` methods on the `Enviroment` class: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to first convert your image to a `Uri`, and then load it using Picasso the same way you did for any images.