# Can't load image from disk with picasso

Tags: android, picasso

At, first i search in Stackoverflow and internet and find many answers but when i try these answers but no answers can solve my problem. in my project i create a directory that name is `files`.

[image]

```
    Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load("file:///files/img_4.jpg").error(R.drawable.eboss).into(imgArticle);
```

or

```
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load("/files/img_4.jpg").error(R.drawable.eboss).into(imgArticle);
```

or

```
 File f = new File("files/img_4");
        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(f).error(R.drawable.eboss).into(imgArticle);
```

or

```
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load("file:/files/img_4.jpg").error(R.drawable.eboss).into(imgArticle);
```

but nothing work and i only see error image.

Comment: can you post the error message..

Comment: @Keshav1234 it dosen't show me any text error .

Comment: why do you not put the images in `\res\drawable` and avoid all the complexity? is there a specific reason to have it in `\src\main\files` folder?

Comment: @Virus i have more than 200 images and save image name in database. so i want a way to load images.

Comment: you could also load the drawable resource by name using `Drawable d= DrawableManager.getDrawable("img_4.png");` and then use the drawable object to load your image from resources.

Comment: @Virus the problem is i have some content each content have images.forexample one article has img_1.jpg and another article has img_1.jpg too so i cant use R for same name except using prefix for image name.

Comment: you don't need to use R as prefix. See the snippet in the above comment where you just need to give the file name as a parameter. Also posted the same as an answer below.

Comment: @Virus yes you right but the next problem with R is directory level. my image is placed in 100 sperated directory and R or `getDraw....` method i think can get one level directory.

Comment: yes that is true. But, I would prefer using a naming convention instead of directories. Just thinking in terms of avoiding processing power damage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load image from files too. Picasso allows that.Here is that from Picasso.

```
RESOURCE LOADING

Resources, assets, files, content providers are all supported as image sources.

Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView1);
Picasso.with(context).load("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView2);
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(...)).into(imageView3);
```

load(new File(...)) - BUT File here must be the ones that are created in /data/data/package.name/...

**So either copy file to assets or specify path to /data/data/package.name/... or from sdcard. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28983967/3209739) to know how to load from sdcard.** You can create a file here using [getFilessDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()).

I think there is no files/ folder in android project structure. You may like to take a look at [Managing Projects Overview](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html).

Comment: "Picasso.with(context).load("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView2);" <-- worked for me as a charm. Thanks @crg

Answer (score 1):

`Picasso` will load images from the sdcard on your device, not from your `AndroidStudio` project. What you could do is to move your picture in the `drawable-nodpi` folder (create it if it does not exist yet), and then you can load the picture like

```
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.img_4).error(R.drawable.e;boss).into(imgArticle);
```

If you want to put the file as part of `assets` then your directory should be called `assets` and not `files`. You can read more [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure)

Comment: I save image name in sqlite tables. so i need a way to show images with picasso.so where save my images ?

Comment: but in picasso website i see this `Picasso.with(context).load("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView2);
` so is android_asset part of android studio or not ?

Comment: assets is fine. But it is called `assets` and not `files`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments on your question I think the reason you want to use the "files" folder is because you want to pick the image by name retrieved from the database.

The same is very well possible if the images are still kept in the drawable folder which is generally the case.

You can get the drawable resource using the name picked from the database as follows:

```
Drawable d= DrawableManager.getDrawable("img_4.png");
```

This will lead to less load on processor in lookup and reading from storage and less code.

And if you must get the resourse id by the image name use this:

```
int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("drawableName", "drawable", this.getPackageName());
```

and then pass the integer id instead of R.drawable.drawableName